# Minimize a function

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Suppose you are given a function of a single variable and arguments a and b and are asked to find the minimum value that the function takes on the interval [a, b].  (You can assume that the argument is a double, though in my application I may need to use an arbitrary-precision library.)

In general this is a hard problem because functions can be weird.  A simple version of this problem would be to minimize the function assuming that it is *continuous* (no gaps or jumps) and *single-peaked* (there is a unique minimum; to the left of the minimum the function is decreasing and to the right it is increasing).  Is there a good way to solve this easier (but perhaps not easy!) problem?

Assume that the function may be difficult to calculate but not particularly expensive to store an answer that you've computed.  (Obviously, it's better if you don't have to make giant arrays of key/value pairs.)

Bonus points for good ideas on improving the algorithm in the fortunate case in which it's nice (e.g.: derivative exists, function is smooth/analytic, derivative can be computed in closed form, derivative can be computed at no cost when the function is evaluated).

Comment: "to the left of the minimum the function is decreasing" - I don't think that would be the *minimum*, then.

Comment: @Greg: every function is decreasing to the left of the minimum. (It decreases as *x* goes to the right.)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: The values decrease until they hit the minimum, then increase.  You're looking at it backward (admittedly, probably because of the way I described it).

Comment: Hasn't Mathematica tackled most of this?

Comment: @linuxuser27: the closed form of the function may or not be given. If it's not, symbolic algorithms don't apply, only numeric ones.

Comment: Why not just use one of the many algorithms for minimization? In 1-d, they are not even that sophisticated. Don't reinvent the wheel!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Charles: Oh, I see what you mean now. Well, that's actually the way to a solution: If you take the derivative of your function, the derivative is negative to the left of a minimum and positive to the right. Use a root-finding algorithm to find the zeroes of the derivative.

Comment: @woodchips: Indeed, that is my purpose in posting this question.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: In general I do not have access to the derivative of the function.

Comment: @Charles When you say you don't have the derivative do you mean (1) "I don't have the derivative because even though I have the source, the function is computed by a complex bit of code so I wouldn't dream of trying to write it out and differentiate it" or (2) "the function is computed by a some black box code I can never examine" or (3) other?

Comment: Buy a copy of numerical recipes.

Comment: @user207442: I have a particular problem in mind for which (1) applies.  But this has happened often enough to me that I'm writing a program to solve it, somewhat efficiently, in general.  In that case I'm in situation (2): I'll pass the function code but it won't be smart enough to compute a derivative (if, indeed, one can be computed reasonably at all).

Comment: @Charles I just want to point out AD as a method that can often compute those derivatives even if it seems too hard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automatic-differentiation

Comment: @user207442: Heh, my numerical analysis prof told me (after I had graduated) that I should get into AD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you describe, with a single minimum, is easy to solve.

The idea is this.  Suppose that I have 3 points with `a < b < c` and `f(b) < f(a)` and `f(b) < f(c)`.  Then the true minimum is between `a` and `c`.  Furthermore if I pick another point `d` somewhere in the interval, then I can throw away one of `a` or `d` and still have an interval with the true minimum in the middle.  My approximations will improve exponentially quickly as I do more iterations.

We don't quite start with this.  We start with 2 points, `a` and `b`, and know that the answer is somewhere in the middle.  Take the mid-point.  If `f` there is below the end points, we're into the case I discussed above.  Otherwise it must be below one of the end points, and above the other.  We can throw away the higher end point and repeat.

Comment: Excellent.  Now that I look into this I think this is the downhill simplex heuristic for 1-D, which for my very nice function always converges.

Comment: I think this is the essence of Brent's algorithm, though I don't know how it compares to the Boost implementation I mentioned in my answer. (I wouldn't be surprised if there were opportunities for optimization, especially in the choice of the next point to evaluate at each iteration.)

Comment: @jim-lewis: You're right.  I have a tendency to figure out how to do things and then later learn that they have a name.

Comment: This is wrong. (consider f = |x|, a = -1, b = +-(1/2) and c = 1).

Comment: @Jim Lewis: I agree that there are probably good ways to choose the points.  If the function is smooth enough and the function expensive enough to calculate, I could imagine saving the k points closest to the best so far and doing polynomial interpolation...

Comment: Oh sorry, I read it completely wrong. Must be the pixies. (Check out my answer though - there is a link to a more traditional algorithm for this)

Answer (score 2):

If the function is nice, i.e., single-peaked and strictly monotonic (i.e., strictly decreasing to the left of the minimum and strictly increasing to the right), then you can find the minimum with binary search:

- Set `x = (b-a)/2`
- test whether `x` is to the right of the minimum or to the left
- if `x` is left of the minimum:`b = x`
- if `x` is right of the minimum:`a = x`
- repeat from start until you get bored
- the minimum is at `x`

To test whether `x` is left/right of the minimum, invent a small value `epsilon` and check whether `f(x - epsilon) < f(x + epsilon)`. If it is, the minimum is to the left, otherwise it's to the right. By "until you get bored", I mean: invent another small value `delta` and stop if `fabs(f(x - epsilon) - f(x + epsilon)) < delta`.

Note that in the general case where you don't know anything about the behavior of a function f, it's not possible to decide a non-trivial property of f. Well, unless you're willing to try all possible inputs. See [Rice's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) for details.

Comment: Fortunately I do know things about the function, otherwise it would be quite hopeless as you suggest.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost project has an implementation of [Brent's algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/minima.html) that may be useful.
It seems to assume that the function is continuous, and has no maxima (only a minimum) in the input interval.

Comment: The OP tagged his posting "language-agnostic"

Comment: ...but the OP still appreciates working code as an example.  In this case the algorithm takes a literal book to describe and would be too much work to implement (can't use it as-is, I need arbitrary precision).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but a pointer to more reading:

- scipy.optimize: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html
- section e04 of naglib: http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/cl/nagdoc_cl09/html/genint/libconts.html

For the special case where the function is differentiable twice (and the two derivatives can be calculated easily), one can use [Newton's method for optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), i.e. essentially finding the roots of the first derivative (which is a necessary condition for the minimum).

Concerning the general case, note that the extreme case of 'weird' is a function which is [continuous nowhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function) and for which it is very hard if not impossible to find the minimum (in finite time). So I guess you should try to make at least *some* assumptions about the function you are trying to minimize.

Comment: The assumptions are in my original question, and are quite strong: the function is continuous and single-peaked.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to optimize an [Unimodal function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodal_function). The correct algorithm is similar to btilly's but you need extra points.

```
Take 4 points a < b < c < d.
We want to minimize f in [a,d].

If f(b) < f(c) we know the minimum is in [a, c]
If f(b) > f(c) "  "    "   "       is in [b, d]
```

This can give an algorithm by itself, but there is a nice [trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) involving the golden ratio that allows you to reuse the intermediate values (in a way you only need to compute f once per iteration instead of twice)

Comment: As you noted in a comment to my answer, my solution is also correct.  However this is a nice way to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expression for the function, there are global optimization algorithms based on interval analysis.

Comment: I do not.  I have a black box that gives me values when I give it arguments.